# How to retrieve as integer data from properties file in java

Tags: java, properties, arraylist

```
String a=prop.getProperty("winningChances");
ArrayList<String> arrayFromString =new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(a.split("/")));
for (int i = 0; i < arrayFromString.size(); i++) {
winChanceArray.add((arrayFromString.get(i)));
}
```

In the above coding I'm fetching data from a property file. And I have to store it as integer format. But the data in properties file is string in default. I couldnt know how handle it as integer. I tried using parseInt method. It is not working.
Value in properties file will be in format `winningChances=1,2,3/1,4,7/1,5,9/2,5,8/3,6,9/3,5,7/4,5,6/7,8,9`

Comment: what do you mean by parseInt is not working? Can you show the error?

Comment: Can you show the line from your Properties file for winningChanes?

Comment: NumberformatException. I have stored the following numbers in property file "1,2,3". And I'm fetching those numbers to compare with the userdata.

winningChances=1,2,3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
userdata. winningChances=1,2,3
```

are seperated by `,` and you are using `/` as seperator

As you mentiones value will be in format `1,2,3/1,4,7/1,5,9/2,5,8/3,6,9/3,5,7/4,5,6/7,8,9`
so first split by `/`  and then split by `,` or remove `,` and use parseInt

Something like

```
input = "1,2,3/1,4,7/1,5,9/2,5,8";
ArrayList<String> splitBySlash = new ArrayList<String>();
splitBySlash.addAll(Arrays.asList(a.split(",")));
```

so it will have `1,2,3` , `1,4,7` and `1,5,9`
not either split again by `,` if you want output as 1,2,3,1,4,7,1,5,9 or remove `,` and use parseInt to get output as 123,147,159

Comment: yes by /. winningChances=1,2,3/1,4,7/1,5,9/2,5,8/3,6,9/3,5,7/4,5,6/7,8,9

Answer (score 1):

you can use ...

```
 String arrayFromString[] = s.split("[/]+");
 String updatedArrayFromString[] = new String[50];
    for(int i=0 ; i< arrayFromString.length;i++)
    {
        updatedArrayFromString[i] = arrayFromString[i].replace("," , "");
    }
    Arrays.asList(updatedArrayFromString);
    for (String str : updatedArrayFromString)
    {
       if(str != null)
        winChanceArray.add(Integer.parseInt(str));
    }
```

if you have any other delimiter u can add it in your split() parameters .

Comment: For this Line winChanceArray.add(Integer.parseInt(str)); NumberFormatException is thrown.

Comment: strings are immutable objects and in my previous code i was trying to modify string .... that was causing the problem . Now its resolved

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this ..

```
String a = prop.getProperty("winningChances");

ArrayList<String> arrayFromString = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<Integer> winChanceArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

arrayFromString.addAll(Arrays.asList(a.split(",")));

for (String str : arrayFromString)
{
    winChanceArray.add(Integer.parseInt(str));
}

for (Integer i : winChanceArray)
{
    System.out.print(i+" ");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MyProg {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "100";
        int num = Integer.parseInt(str);
        System.out.println(num * 2);
    }
}

--output:--
200
```

Comment: The data in the OP's properties file is stored in this format: `1,2,3/1,4,7/1,5,9/2,5,8/3,6,9/3,5,7/4,5,6/7,8,9`. You need more than just `Integer.parseInt`...

Comment: @SimonMcKenzie, Well gee whiz, maybe the op edited their post after I posted my answer.